# If a text in a TextView is longer than the available space, how to get the remaining lines?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a long text and i want it to be displayed with a TextView. The text i have is much longer than the available space. However i don't want to use scrolling, but ViewFlipper to flip to the next page. How can i retrieve the lines from the first TextView that are not shown because the view is to short so that i can paste them into the next TextView?

Edit: I found the Solution to my Problem. I simply have to use a custom View with a StaticLayout like this:

```
public ReaderColumView(Context context, Typeface typeface, String cText) {
        super(context);
        Display display = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        dWidth = display.getWidth(); 
        dHeight = display.getHeight();

        contentText = cText;

        tp = new TextPaint();
        tp.setTypeface(typeface);
        tp.setTextSize(25);
        tp.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        tp.setAntiAlias(true);

        StaticLayout measureLayout = new StaticLayout(contentText, tp, 440, Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1, 2, true);
        Boolean reachedEndOfScreen = false;
        int line = 0;
        while (!reachedEndOfScreen) {
            if (measureLayout.getLineBottom(line) > dHeight-30) {
            reachedEndOfScreen = true;
            fittedText = contentText.substring(0, measureLayout.getLineEnd(line-1));
            setLeftoverText(contentText.substring(measureLayout.getLineEnd(line-1)));
            }

            line++;

        }
    }
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        StaticLayout textLayout = new  StaticLayout(fittedText, tp, 440, Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1, 2, true);
        canvas.translate(20,20);
        textLayout.draw(canvas);
    }
```

Thats not optimized yet but you get the point.
I hope it might help somebody like me with a similar problem.

Comment: You should consider a self-answered question. Otherwise it's not clear that there is an answer.

Comment: you should not create a StaticLayout during onDraw, it is very expensive, especially for long text.

Answer (score 0):

As in your answer you can use StaticLayout to measure and draw the text. However,

- You should not create a StaticLayout during onDraw, it is very expensive, especially for long text. Instead you should create it once during onMeasure and reuse it.
- For your while loop looking for the line to end (while (!reachedEndOfScreen)), you can use StaticLayout.getLineForVertical(int offset).
- Instead of substring, or leftOverText you can use indices and pass those indices to StaticLayout for each page.